# Player Betrayal Question

Tags: discussion

Why was: [Incentivizing Player Betrayal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25338/incentivizing-player-betrayal) voted as off-topic?

Comment: My guess: Someone suggested that it sounded board-game-like, someone else hit "close" on that justification, and it snowballed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure @BESW has the right of it and that's all it was.

Comment: Yeah, I voted close for that exact reason -- in my first read through the question I misinterpreted "not character driven" to imply a board-game like nature.